# Passing variable with Mapnik.filter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mapnik

I was wondering if there is a way of passing a variable as the XML query in mapnik.filter().

Namely, we know we can do the following:

```
rule=mapnik.Rule()
rule.filter=mapnik.Filter("[NAME]='test'")
```

to obtain a map which does something special if the NAME of something is 'test'. However, I would like to do the following:

```
s="[NAME]='test'"
rule=mapnik.Rule()
rule.filter=mapnik.Filter(s)
```

This, however, doesn't seem to be working, giving the following error:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
mapnik._mapnik.Expression()
did not match C++ signature:
Expression(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
std::allocator<char> > expr)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277708/boost-python-argumenterror-python-str-not-converted-to-stdstring) the OP works directly with Boost Python and is able to convert his string to an immutable one; I, however, am just working with Mapnik, which is a package which uses BoostPython in the background, so it's unlikely a similar solution would work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that your variable is pointing to a string of characters (unicode), whereas the C++ library is after an encoded string. Encoding it like this will therefore work:

```
s="[NAME]='test'".encode('utf-8')
rule=mapnik.Rule()
rule.filter=mapnik.Filter(s)
```

You can also use the `str()` function, though I have read that this is a less robust approach and should be avoided in favour of the above. I believe that the difference arises when you have non-ASCII characters in your string (which is not the case for the below, which works fine):

```
s=str("[NAME]='test'")
rule=mapnik.Rule()
rule.filter=mapnik.Filter(s)
```

Nevertheless, I think that you are safest sticking with the first example.

If you want to verify that it works, you can so so by passing your variable to the `type()` function. Before encoding, this will give you

```
s="[NAME]='test'"
print type(s)

<type 'unicode'>
```

Whereas after you will get

```
s="[NAME]='test'".encode('utf-8')
print type(s)

<type 'str'>
```

If you want to read more about the unicode vs encoded strings stuff, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) is a good place to start. It is also worth noting that the situation is a little different in Python 3 (equivalent doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)).